# Is LeakCanary alone enough for hunting down memory leaks?

Tags: memory-leaks, leakcanary

I've been using LeakCanary for a while now. It does a strikingly good job especially when considering how easy it is to integrate to any apps anyone might have out there.

But is LeakCanary alone going to be enough to hunt down these leaks? How much should I depend on it (especially for optimising production apps)?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a pretty abstract question...is notepad enough to write android apps?  Leak canary is a tool that will help you find leaks, some by default and some through additional refwatchers but at the end of the days its just a tool.  If you are not confident with the level of leak detection in leak canary, you can also try to do heap dumps into DDMS for complete analysis of what is on your heap at a certain time.